# Seeking large file with off64_t offset not working

Tags: c++, fseek

This is supposed to be very simple seeking operation on large file, however it always fails and never changes the offset. I have the feeling I'm missing something in my code.
Minimal reproducible example:

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
#define __USE_FILE_OFFSET64 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    FILE* file = fopen64("data", "w+b");
    off64_t offset1 = 5000;
    off64_t offset2 = 1013309916216033280;
    fseeko64(file, offset1, SEEK_SET);
    std::cout << "Offset at: " << ftello64(file);
    fseeko64(file, offset2, SEEK_SET);
    std::cout << " Offset at: " << ftello64(file);
    if(offset2 != ftello64(file)){
        std::cerr << "Cannot seek to offset2.";
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output is "Offset at: 5000 Offset at: 1013309916216033280"

Current output is "Cannot seek to offset2.Offset at: 5000Offset at: 5000"

Have I misunderstood the functionality of the fseeko64 function? or am I implementing it the wrong way??
Also, perror function is printing "Invalid Argument" without any more details.

Comment: ftell(), ftello(), ftello64() : return the current position of a stream's file pointer

Comment: You really have a file with `1013309916216033280` bytes?  Great reason to always check the return to determine if the function succeeded or failed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin probably not. 1013309916216033280 B = 1013309 TB

Comment: @paladin I'm aware of ftello64 functionality, I just used it to show that the file offset has not changed after the second fseeko64.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the number in this example is just random, any number larger than 32 bits is failing. Also, the file I'm working with is sparse, so reaching such number is not out of question, but that doesn't mean all that data is allocated, probably less than 20% is.

Comment: You can't just use "random" numbers and hope that it works - lol - check your file size. Create a 5GB sized file and use a offset greater than 2^32, but less than 5G to test your program.

Comment: @paladin in my original program i am the one writing the sparse file in binary mode. The offset reaches even higher numbers

Comment: So you have a 1013309 TB sized file. Nice RAID system! - **sarcasm off** - I suggest you read a book about fundamental computer technology, especially about storaging data.

Comment: @paladin I have a sparse file with such offset, the actual storage is within 100 GB.

Comment: 1013309916 GB is greater than 100 GB .

Comment: @paladin again, sparse file.

Comment: Your "sparse file emulator" doesn't support file sizes greater than 2^32. Use a real file. `dd bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=~/realfile count=5000 status=progress && sync` Just to make sure, you are using a 64bit OS, right?

Comment: @paladin using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64bit. Again, I'm creating and writing to the file in my use case, but since fseeko64 is failing all data with offset after 4GB is being written to offset 0.

Comment: Again, your "usecase" does specify a file size of 1013309916216033280 bytes. I'm pretty sure your file is not that big.

Comment: @paladin fine, you want actual numbers, here you go, offsets taken at random from error log: 1306043891995115520,  720575940415979520, 427841964647383040, 292733975784325120, 22517998142095360, and they all produce same error. Now could we stop discussing minor unrelated details and get to the real question of why fseeko64 is giving Invalid Argument for 64bit offset?

Comment: I just used your program, changed `off64_t offset2 = 5000000000;`, and created a file with `dd bs=1M if=/dev/zero of=./data count=5000 status=progress && sync` and it works.

Comment: I'm the one creating the file in c++ not reading from it. So using dd to create file is not an option, additionally max size is not known in advance.

Comment: So you might guess your OS/program might have problems when trying to create a file of size 1013309916216033280 bytes or whatever.

Comment: For example: ext4 filesystem: max. file size 16 TiB (for 4 KiB block size)

Comment: @paladin do you know what a sparse file is? That `dd` doesn't create a sparse file because how can it know the content of the file to create holes on that? You must use tools like ftruncate or you'll have to seek with dd https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Sparse_file

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. A file in ext4 just can't be bigger than 16TiB (for 4KiB block size), may it virtual or real file size. You also should check your sparse file emulator, aka truncate for 64bit addressing capacities. You should check your local environment settings for maximum allowed file size, you should check your OS being able to handle sparse files correctly. You should at least tell us what filesystem you use. ZFS filesystem supports much larger files. If you don't want to check all this, you just create a real file with `dd` like I've done and use this real file for tests.